# Pulling certain key/value pairs from core data fetched results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

:D Apologies I am brand new to this and I am trying to wrap my head around core data. I have two view controllers. the first one (called PVC) is a table view controller with two sections that holds names and emails that a user enters. They press add from that screen and it takes them to the second view controller (called PDVC) where the user adds the name and email and specifies which section the entry will fall under (trustee or recipient). When they hit done on that screen, the info gets saved into core data and it takes them back to the PVC where core data fetches that info and puts it into the table view.

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the user taps send from the PVC, I need to take that info, (each name and email entered) JSON it, and send it off to a server. I'm doing this successfully with a hack I conjured up that stores each item into the dictionary, and then takes those key/value pairs and adds them to a mutable array all from the PDVC. The problem is, all of this data needs to be as persistent as core data so it makes sense to use core data for this info instead of my hack. My question is, is that possible? I need to be able to 'extract' certain key value pairs from core data. If I can do that, I'm sure I can figure out the rest. I understand that theres a method you can use to store core data info into an array but it also comes along with other info that I can't use:

```
array of fetched objects: (
"<Credentials: 0xb9c6ed0> (entity: Credentials; id: 0xb9bfa90 <x-coredata://BE51A026-9D1B-      4A93-BA34-4EAC55B8B9DF/Credentials/p1> ; data: {\n    category = Trustees;\n    name = aef;\n     settingsEmail = \"inawef@hioe.com\";\n})",
"<Credentials: 0xb9c6f40> (entity: Credentials; id: 0xb9c6ae0 <x-coredata://BE51A026-9D1B- 4A93-BA34-4EAC55B8B9DF/Credentials/p3> ; data: {\n    category = Trustees;\n    name = awef;\n     settingsEmail = \"waef@aioc.com\";\n})",
"<Credentials: 0xb9c6fc0> (entity: Credentials; id: 0xb9c6af0 <x-coredata://BE51A026-9D1B- 4A93-BA34-4EAC55B8B9DF/Credentials/p2> ;
```

I just need from that info the name and settingsEmail key/value pairs. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the rest of my code

PVC.h

```
@interface PeopleViewController : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
}
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

PVC.m

```
#import "PeopleViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "PeopleDetailViewController.h"
#import "Credentials.h"
#import "AlertLoad.h"
#import "Data.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"


@interface PeopleViewController ()

@end

@implementation PeopleViewController
{
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
AlertLoad *alertLoad;
Data *dataObj;

}
@synthesize managedObjectContext;


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (fetchedResultsController == nil)
{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription        entityForName:@"Credentials" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor   sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor  sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1,  sortDescriptor2, nil]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                sectionNameKeyPath:@"category"
                                cacheName:@"Credentials"];

    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
}
return fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)performFetch
{
NSError *error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
    return;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"view did load");
dataObj = [Data dataObj];
dataObj.trusteeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
dataObj.recipientArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (self.managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  self.managedObjectContext);
    }
[self performFetch];
NSLog(@"array of fetched objects: %@", [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]);
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];


self.navigationItem.title = @"Swipe to delete";
}



 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
// Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

PeopleDetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;


}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//return [listOfItems count];
return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]   objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController  sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo name];

}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

Credentials *credentials = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([credentials.name length] > 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = credentials.name;
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"(New Entry)";
}
if (credentials.settingsEmail != nil)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = credentials.settingsEmail;
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Tap to edit";
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    Credentials *credentials = [self.fetchedResultsController  objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:credentials];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
        return;
    }
}
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
// Set up the cell...

return cell;
}


-(void)infoSent
{
[alertLoad close];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your trustees and recipients have been submitted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)sendDataWithString:(NSString *)string
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lastwords.com.au/lastwords/"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:dataObj.username              forKey:@"author"];
[request setPostValue:dataObj.password              forKey:@"password"];
[request setPostValue:string                        forKey:@"participants"];
[request setPostValue:@"set_participants"           forKey:@"json"];
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (error != nil)
{
    [alertLoad close];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(infoSent) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

}

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender
{

if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 3)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Too many trustees" message:@"You can only submit a maximum of 3 trustees." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] < 3)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Not enough trustees"  message:@"You must select 3 trustees." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] < 2)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No trustees or recipients" message:@"You must enter at least enter 3 trustees and at least one recipient." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

else
{
    alertLoad = [[AlertLoad alloc]
                 initWithTitle:@"Submitting..."
                 message:@"Submitting your trustees and recipients. Please wait...\n\n\n"
                 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alertLoad.delegate = self;

    [alertLoad show];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dataObj.trusteeArray,@"trustees", dataObj.recipientArray,  @"recipients", nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString* jSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json??: %@", jSONString);
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sendDataWithString:) withObject:jSONString];


}

}



@end
```

(took out fetch results delegate stuff to save space)

PDVC.h

```
@interface PeopleDetailViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFieldEmail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end
```

PDVC.m

```
#import "PeopleDetailViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Credentials.h"
#import "Data.h"

@interface PeopleDetailViewController ()

{
Data *dataObj;
}
@end

@implementation PeopleDetailViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"view did load");
dataObj = [Data dataObj];

if (self.managedObjectContext == nil)
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  self.managedObjectContext);
}
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - textField Delegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];

return YES;
}



- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

if (self.txtFieldEmail.text.length < 1 || self.txtFieldName.text.length < 1)
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.txtFieldEmail.text] == NO)
{
    //Valid email addres
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid email" message:@"Please enter a valid email address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
}

else
{
    Credentials *credentials = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Credentials" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    credentials.name = self.txtFieldName.text;
    credentials.settingsEmail = self.txtFieldEmail.text;

    if (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        credentials.category = @"Trustees";
        NSDictionary *trusteeDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.txtFieldName.text,@"name", self.txtFieldEmail.text,@"email", nil];
        NSError *error;
        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:trusteeDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSString* jSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"json??: %@", jSONString);
        [dataObj.trusteeArray addObject:trusteeDict];
        NSLog(@"trusteeArray: %@", dataObj.trusteeArray);

    }
    else
    {
        credentials.category = @"Recipients";
        NSDictionary *recipientDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.txtFieldName.text,@"name", self.txtFieldEmail.text,@"email", nil];
        NSError *error;
        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:recipientDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSString* jSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"json??: %@", jSONString);
        [dataObj.recipientArray addObject:recipientDict];
        NSLog(@"recipientArray: %@", dataObj.recipientArray);
    }

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
    FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
    return;
    }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing but you can fetch specific information from core data with 2 very simple approaches.

1) use a predicate in the fetch like this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID = %@", userIDYouAreLookingfor];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",fetchedObjects);
```

2) A parent relation has its entities specified in a NSSet, you can test them to retrieve certain objects:

```
NSSet *picturesResult = [_thumbnailsStorage.pictures objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        Picture *pic = obj;
        // Check for a condition here
        if (someCondition) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];
```

If this is not what you asked let me know and ill see if I can help.

Comment: hey Luis. Thank you so much for getting back to me. Basically, my Core Data entity has 3 attributes: category, name and email. I need to be able to get the name and email attribute from each entry in the core database put into an array, JSON that info and send it off to a server. I tried suggestion #1 but got a crash probably because i didn't set it up right for my context. can you tell me where  self.connectionManager.yesterscapeID is coming from? Is that from core data?

Comment: option 1 retrieves all the entities from the class that yous pecify, when the user taps one of the entries all you have to do is get the name or email and look for it coredata. the predicate is used for this, it means, look for entries whos userID is equal to something. you can replace userID for name or email depending on how you set up those properties in core data. I do not understand why you want to do this if you seem to be displaying this information somehow, you should take the values directly from there and retrieve them. unless there is data you are not displaying that interests u.

Comment: oooh ok I see what you mean now. In that case I'm not sure if predicates are what I should be using. I'm actually not trying to search for a specific entry. I have a table view full of names and email addresses. Every cell has a name as a title and an email as a subtitle. I need to send that name and email off to a server. Is my problem even related to core data? lol. I may need to ask a different question.

Comment: no, actually it has nothing to do with coredata, if you already have the table filled and you are registering the selection or press or something of a specific cell then you can very easily read this cell's title and subtitle and send those without even interacting with core data. (probably where you select the cell and take the actions one of the parameters recieved is index i think, you can use this to get the cell, i dont remember very well but yes you are in the wrong track here)

Comment: you put me on the right track Luis. Thanks much. Credit for you!